# <%@ Page Debug="True" ...... %>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does setting this value have the same effect as setting the  debug="true" in the web.config file? If not, what does it do?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it only turns on debugging for a specific page (ie. the compiler generates debugging symbols for just that page's class), not the entire site. However, not having site level debugging on will probably stop you running the Visual Studio debugger, so take that into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it overrides a Debug=false setting from the config file. But it is only valid for the 1 page it is in.